# Dashcode (3.0.5) crashes in Mountain Lion (10.8.4)

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm trying to get Dashcode to run in order to make a dashboard widget to surprise my friend. The app opens but crashes almost instantly (even in safe mode and Mavericks). The console yields the following errors:

```
6/23/2013 10:38:23.041 PM Dashcode[743]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
6/23/2013 10:38:23.043 PM Dashcode[743]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
```

Comment: The guide on [Ask] will help you refine your question by showing what you've tried and/or what exactly "you don't get". If you don't get a good answer, feel free to try editing in some details or links on what question you used and what step is failing or doesn't make sense. We love details here.

Comment: That's really all there is to it. I open dash code, it locks up and requires a force quit. I've tried deleting it's temp files, and I've tried on both 10.8.4 and 10.9 DP 1. I showed the errors given, and beyond that, I can't think of any other details to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashcode interacts with the iPhoto library on startup - Start iPhoto with the option and command buttons held down. You then get an option to rebuild the library (there are four different radio buttons, start at the top - checking whether DashCode launches between each rebuild - if it doesn't work still try the next rebuild option in iPhoto)

Comment: Wow lol that actually worked